# timestamp as file name in java

Tags: java, sql, timestamp

I need to create a text file in the name of current timestamp in a particular directory

> D:\Assignments\abassign in java.

But when i try to do that the following error comes as the file name should not contain ':'. But the timestamp contains ':'

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
>       at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
>       at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:883)
>       at abassign.Abassign.main(Abassign.java:35)
>   Java Result: 1

This error shows up

Comment: `.replace(":", ".")` on the string formatted timestamp

Comment: Do it the right way! Take a look at `SimpleDateFormat`, which will format your time to a more flexible pattern like `"year_month_day_hour_min_sec"` format without any reserved characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Windows your file name cannot contain `:`, you need to replace it by another character...

The following characters are reserved :

```
< (less than)
> (greater than)
: (colon)
" (double quote)
/ (forward slash)
\ (backslash)
| (vertical bar or pipe)
? (question mark)
* (asterisk)
```

For example :

```
String yourTimeStamp = "01-01-2016 17:00:00";
File yourFile = new File("your directory", yourTimeStamp.replace(":", "_"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I use something like this:

```
    StringBuffer fn = new StringBuffer();
    fn.append(workingDirectory);
    fn.append("/");
    fn.append("fileNamePrefix-");
    fn.append("-");
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss");
    fn.append(df.format(new Date()));
    fn.append("-fileNamePostFix.txt");
    return fn.toString();
```

(Of course, you can drop the prefix, postfix and workingDirectory parts)

Answer (score 0):

here is the Code to generate file using time stamp

```
/*
 * created by Sandip Bhoi 9960426568
 */
package checkapplicationisopen;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Random;

public class GeneratorUtil {


        /**
         * 
         * @param args 
         */
    public static void main(String args[])
    {   
            GeneratorUtil generatorUtil=new GeneratorUtil();
            generatorUtil.createNewFile("c:\\Documents", "pdf");
    }



    /**
     * 
     * @param min 
     * @param max
     * @return 
     */
    public static int randInt(int min, int max) {

        // Usually this can be a field rather than a method variable
        Random rand = new Random();

        // nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
        // so add 1 to make it inclusive
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        return randomNum;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param prefix adding the prefix for time stamp generated id
     * @return the concatenated string with id and prefix
     */
    public static String getId(String prefix)
    {
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        String timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime()).toString();
        String dt1 = timestamp.replace('-', '_');
        String dt2 = dt1.replace(' ', '_');
        String dt3 = dt2.replace(':', '_');
        String dt4 = dt3.replace('.', '_');
        int temp = randInt(1, 5000);
        return prefix +"_"+ temp + "_" + dt4;        
    }



        /**
         * 
         * @param direcotory
         * @param extension 
         */
        public void createNewFile(String direcotory,String extension)
        {
            try {

                File file = new File(direcotory+"//"+getId("File")+"."+extension);
                if (file.createNewFile()){
                  System.out.println("File is created!");
                }else{
                  System.out.println("File already exists.");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.